# How to filter to latest date of Opportunities on an Account

Tags: custom-reports, joined-reports, criteria-filter, cross-filter

I’ve spent a good amount of time trying to figure out or find this answer -

I created a report showing fields from both Accounts and Opportunities and there are sometimes multiple Opportunities tied to 1 Account. I want to only show the Opportunity that has the latest date in that field when there are multiple.

Here is a screenshot showing what I am trying to do. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This is not possible out of the box. One solution: create a [roll-up summary field](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/roll_up_summary_fields) on Account that is populated with your latest opportunity's created date, then filter on this field in your report.